# How to prevent VS Code horizontal autoscroll?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code version 1.19
If the line of HTML is too long to be in view, the editor is automatically scrolling horizontally to reveal the end of the line...

How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using "editor.wordWrap": "on" and off in setting

there is also a option to toggle ( in mac os it's option + Z )
to find the shortcuts go to preference -> keyboard shortcuts

Comment: I tried "editor.wordWrap": "off"/"on".  Unfortunately no effect((( Any other ideas?

Comment: set wordWrap on , then save the setting and reload the editor ( it's working for me )

Comment: I mean wordWrapp works and sort of fixes the issue for the code I'm trying to edit but did I mention it also scrolls the open tabs on hover...

Comment: @UlianaPavelko this may be some extension problem , do you have any extension installed  because i never experienced this. may be some kind of tag matcher or something

Comment: I don't like wordWrap, but I want to prevent automatic horizontal scrolling too. Does a way to do that exist?