# How to prevent vertical autoscrolling in VS Code in EJS and JS files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ejs

I'm having an issue with VS Code where my EJS and JS files automatically scroll up whenever I edit code on a lower line. It's worth noting this doesn't happen with CSS or HTML files, just JS and EJS.

I've tried using the solution found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420446/how-to-prevent-vs-code-horizontal-autoscroll), but using wordWrap didn't work for me.

Here's the outcome of the `Help: About` command:

```
Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
```

This happens even with all extensions disabled.